# Automorphism and Inner automorphism

Tags: group-theory

What is an example of an automorphism of a group G that does not belong to Inn(G), the group of all inner automorphisms?

Comment: Any nontrivial automorphism of an abelian group, for starters.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick any automorphism of an abelian group that is not the identity. For example, any invertible linear transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ (which is not the identity) is a non-inner automorphism of $(\mathbb R^n,{+})$. Or, if you want a completely concrete example, how about $f(x)=x^3$ as an automorphism of $\mathbb R^\times$?

For non-abelian groups, the simplest example is probably the automorphism of $A_4$ given by conjugation by the transposition $(1\,2)$. (This is non-inner because $(1\,2)\notin A_4$).

Comment: I would say that your second example non-inner because $C_{S_4}(A_4) = \{1\}$ and $(12) \not\in A_4$. For example $(56) \not\in A_4$, but in $A_4$ conjugation by $(56)$ is the trivial automorphism, which is inner.

Answer (score 4):

All inner automorphism of Abelian groups is identity. $f: g \rightarrow g^{-1}$ is a automorphism for Abelian groups.

Comment: Perhaps it should be added that $f$ is trivial (and thus inner) if and only if the group is an elementary abelian $2$-group.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=\langle  x, y \rangle $ be a free group of rank 2 with $x$ and $y$ as generator words.

Then $\phi: F \rightarrow F$ with $\phi(x)=y$ and $\phi(y)=x$ induce an automorphism of $F$ which is not inner. (note that $F$ is free group so $x$ and $y$ can not be conjugate elements in $F$ since there is no relation in the presentation of a free group).

In fact this example can be extended to any finite-rank free group.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example is probably
$$\begin{align}\phi:\mathbb{Z}_3&\to\mathbb{Z}_3\\ x&\mapsto -x.\end{align}$$